# Solving a sequence of cp_models

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I need to solve a sequence of Google or-tools cp_model SAT problems, in which only one constraint of many changes on each step through the sequence.  Building a new model for each case is extremely inefficient.   Is there a way to vary a parameter in the model, like Parameter() in cvxpy?   Otherwise, is there a way to remove constraint and add a new one in its place?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying storage of the model is a protobuf:

[The CpModel storage](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/cp_model.proto)

You need to keep a reference to the Constraint objet.
To clear a constraint, just access the underlying proto object (`Proto()` in python, `getBuilder()` in java for instance) and call `Clear()` or `clear()` on it.

You can overwrite a constraint in place. But you will need to understand the process to rewrite model object into constraint (look at the `cp_model.cc`, `cp_model.py`, `CpModel.java`, `CpModel.cs` files). The simpler is to append a new constraint using the standard `model.AddXXX` APIs.